# FragmentPagerAdapter implements Parcelable?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, bundle, parcelable, fragmentpageradapter

### My problem

I am using `ViewPager` with custom `FragmentPagerAdapter` - `ThreePageAdapter`. `ThreePageAdapter` consist of 3 pages of `WrapperFragment`. I use `ThreePageAdapter.addFirstPage(Fragment pFragment)` to add fragments into `ThreePageAdapter`. If I minimize my app it will destroy `ThreePageAdapter`. And when I open app again, the app will start `onCreate()` method again. I think it is wrong.

### My question

Should I make my `ThreePageAdapter` implements `Parcelable` to put it into `Bundle` at `onSaveInstanceState()` method? Is it a good practice?

I would greatly appreciate for your help. Alex. P.S. Sorry for my English:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store fragment in bundle you can try Something Like this

```
getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "tag", content);
```

where outState is Bundle, tag is String, content is Fragment